# python regex "parenthesis unbalanced error" on unbuntu but not on macos machine

Tags: python, regex, ubuntu

I'm using following line to search for function call:

```
pattern=fname+"(.*)" # WHERE FNAME IS SOME FUNCTION NAME
```

The code is working fine on my mac, but when I run this on my ubuntu machine, i gets - "unbalanced parenthesis error"

Comment: could you provide the error stacktrace in the question

Answer (score 1):

try to use `string literals`:

```
pattern=fname+r"(.*)"
```

Comment: actually the problem was with the line i was matching, which contained unbalanced parenthesis